# How to replace only IP in url string in file

Tags: java, r.java-file

How to Replace only Ip in the below string in file with java file operation
`var BOSH_URL = "http://192.168.50.107:7070/http-bind/";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use replaceAll

```
BOSH_URL = BOSH_URL.replaceAll("(\\d+.){3}\\d+", "127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: Maybe replaceFirst is better suitable. Otherwise maybe parts of the URL can be replaced, too (not only the ip address).

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to read the files content. Then you could use a regular expression that matches the ip address (e.g. `\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+`) and replace it with the new one. When you've done that write it back in the file again.

Here is a regex tester: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Here a tutorial of how to read and write files: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=392

Comment: I used `newline=line.replaceAll("//.*:", "new IP");` for replace but not worked properly.

Comment: take a look at the regex tester to find out the regex that fits your needs. FYI `//.*` matches everthing after `http:`. So `"http://192.168.50.107:7070/http-bind/"` will become `http:newIP`

Answer (score 1):

As Shoaib Chikate said you can use string concatenation, and I suggest you to use StringBuilder like in `var BOSH_URL = new StringBuilder("http://").append(ipAddress).append(port).append("/http-bind")`

If you chose java regex to replace the IP, you must be very carefully with that; some example posted have flaws. For instance: `"(\\d+.){3}\\d+"` can also match '999.999.999.99999999' which is not a valid IP. Therefore, additional logic is required to check for validity (if that is needed in your case).

OR

Change the BOSH_URL as `var BOSH_URL = "http://@ipAddress:@port/http-bind/"` and after getting the real IP and port you cand do `BOSH_URL.replace("@ipAddress", realIPAddress).replace("@port", realPort);`

Answer (score 0):

To just replace one ip don't write big logic containing replaceFirst replace blah blah blah
Instead declared variable for that and change that variable.

```
var ipAddress=null
var BOSH_URL="http://"+ipAddress+":7070/anyAdress"
```

Comment: yes but port and address is not fixed so..